# Weird Chrome Rendering Issue. Possible Bug?

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser

[Our website](http://www.ereplacementparts.com/), in Chrome, the three cells on the right-hand side of the header are mysteriously pushed down 5 pixels. Notice the borders between the cart, "share", and "shop all brands" and how they extend below the plane.

The page seems to render fine in other browsers like Firefox and IE.

I've spent quite a bit of time trying to figure what is causing things to be pushed down in Chrome. I have reason to suspect it has something to do with the `<div>` within the "shop all brands" `<td>`.

Also it's interesting to note that in a newer beta version of Chrome, the page renders without this strange behavior?  Maybe a bug was fixed?

Comment: it doesn't have valign="top"?

Comment: Nope, that's not it, because the alignment is middle and still lines up the right way in the other browsers.

Comment: I don't know then, it's a bit of a strange way you've coded it so it's hard to tell where the problem is. My advice would be to strip it back to only the elements that cause the problem and work it out from there

Comment: I agree that it is strange. This is a project that I'm inheriting. :)

Comment: I feel bad for you... [you inherited one big mess](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ereplacementparts.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  Try fixing some of the 233 HTML validation errors as they're usually the cause of cross-browser rendering differences.  Also, the site has a bunch of `<style></style>` tags inside the `<body>` section... this is such a bad practice that's so easily avoidable.   With all that invalid HTML, I will safely say that this is likely not a Chrome or Webkit bug.

Comment: Also, can you post a screenshot?  I'm not sure I understand your description of _"they extend below the plane"_.  I'm looking at this in Safari, which is also a Webkit browser like Chrome and I _think_ I'm seeing what you describe.  5 pixels is not that much to be so noticeable.  Should the top of the shopping cart icon be in line with the top edge of the search button?  If so, perhaps you could add this to the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `<div>` surrounding "Shop All Brands" caused the issue to go away. Apparently Chrome likes to add superfluous spacing when a `<div>` is contained within in a table cell in this specific context. 
Again, as I mentioned earlier, this behavior is not present in newer (beta) versions of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may have some extra padding from somewhere. Try setting `padding:0` on the `td` which encloses each element.

Comment: Been down that road, and it's a dead end. I really think this is a bug.

Comment: Weird. According to it's own inspection tool that's what's happening so I don't know what to tell you otherwise. My only other thought would be the fact that the `ul` has `display:block` or that the `a` is `display:inline-block` but I highly doubt it. If that's not it, then good luck finding out what it is.

Comment: Do you mean that visually the inspection tool is showing padding? I see that too. But I don't see any padding being set in the actual "computed style" section of the tool.

Comment: @eysikal, weird things can happen when you have [invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ereplacementparts.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  I'd also move all the `style` tags from the `body` to the `head`.

Answer (score 0):

For the DIV parented at `a.shopallbrands`, having the inline style of `style="margin:0 0 0 10px;"`, modify it to read, `style="margin:0 0 0 10px; height: 19px;"`.

Comment: I actually ended up removing the `<div>` completely and just adding some `padding-left` to the `<td>`. I will try what you just suggested in a sec.

Comment: I tried it and it looked ok on one monitor. On my monitor with a higher res it actually pushed the "all" in "shop all brands" to a new line. So that "shop all brands" shows up each word stacked upon each other on its own line.

Comment: I tried it and it looked ok on one monitor. On my monitor with a higher res it actually pushed the "all" in "shop all brands" to a new line. So that "shop all brands" shows up each word stacked upon each other on its own line.

Comment: Can you explain your logic behind your answer? Is there something that was setting the height by default to something that was too high?

Comment: This change reduces the height of the tallest element that implicitly increases the overall height of the entire row. Unfortunately, I don't have a very-high-res monitor to tune this :( You can also try moving up the DIV by having the inline style say `margin:-5px 0 0 10px;`.

Comment: Ok, so the `<div>` somehow magically adds height to that cell and then by default, the rest of the row? Right? I think that's question I'm asking. Why does this happen and should it?

Comment: You are correct. The `<div>`'s height is dynamic, which means it is determined by the layout engine to accommodate its children. Now, the height of a `<tr>` is determined by its tallest `<td>` which is also expanded to hold its child `<div>`. And there's no magic here :) You just appear to have that `<td>`'s height slightly (by 5px) exceed the previous tallest `<td>`, nothing else. Setting a negative top margin on the div effectively reduces the height by 5px to line up with the rest of the `<td>`s.

Comment: Cool. Except that the same thing doesn't happen in other browsers on that same `<div>`.

Comment: That may depend on the user-agent stylesheets or rendering quirks... oh, by the way, did you try switching between the quirks/strict mode for your page?

Comment: I didn't try that, no. But I already know it would a disaster. :)